# Dbatools - Get-[DbaDatabase] Failure | The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, amazon-ec2, dbatools

I am new to powershell and dbatools and currently testing a script on an ec2 built-in Microsoft SQL Server 2022. This script should simply create full and differential backup jobs of all databases to a specified path and also pushes backups to a S3 bucket.

However when I run basic dbatools commands I get below warning and it won`t pull any databases.

```
WARNING: [Get-DbaDatabase] Failure | The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted
```

I`ve read setting "TrustServerCertificate" to True fixes the problem in the connection string, but how to bypass this issue when running on a script in powershell with dbatools as it throws an error when adding -TrustServerCertificate to any dbatools command.

Comment: You should really just install a proper certificate, either by paying a public CA for it, or through your private Enterprise CA. `TrustServerCertificate` is insecure